# asp.net & jquery fade effect

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page with a button named "projects",a div id="main"> and a label inside it. The main text of the page is written in the label. When I press the button, the text changes, using the label.text = .. inside the button_Click event inside C#. This is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="projects" runat="server" OnClick="projects_Click"/>
```

What I want to do is to add a fading effect when changing the text. I saw that the easiest way was to use jQuery. I added this:

```
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function () {
      $("#projects").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#main').fadeOut(1000);
          $("#main").fadeIn(1000);              
      });          
   });
 </script>
</head>
```

What happens now is that if I press the projects button, the text only fades out and then it fades in, but it's not changed, projects_Click isn't executed. If I remove e.preventDefault(); , the text changes but there is no fading effect. How can I make them work together? Old text fades out, projects_Click is executed and fadeIn comes into action.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between serve-side functionality and client side functionality. Javasctipt/jQuery executes on the brower, asp.net on the server. Ajax is often used to bridge that gap. With the code you have `preventDefault();` is stopping the server side code from executing as that is the default action for the button.

Comment: Have you tried my solution (part#2)?

Comment: I told you to user `animate()` - custom JS function and invoke that from button click, but you did it completely incorrect way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move following part(mentioned in your question) to JS , then it will work..

```
When I press the button, the text changes, using the label.text = .. inside the button_Click event inside C#.
```

Lets say that text is XYZ, then you can do it like this.

```
 $(function () {
      $("#projects").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#main").html("XYZ");
          $('#main').fadeOut(1000);
          $("#main").fadeIn(1000);              
      });          
   });
```

And if that is calculated on server side, then move those code block to a `webmethod` and do a `ajax call` in `.click` event and in success handler set text and do animations.

Tutorial for above - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

**OR**

I have one more suggestion .

1. Define a javascript function in aspx. Like following.

> ```
> function animate(){
>     $('#main').fadeOut(1000);
>     $("#main").fadeIn(1000);   
> }
> ```

2. In button click handler, after setting label text, use following line to initiate animation on page load ( after page postback / button click event handler completes).

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scr", "<script>animate();</script>");`

**NOTE** - you can not simultaneously use server side code to set some text or do `preventDefault` to set animation in JS. This will make you in catch 22 situation.

Answer (score 0):

The text is too large to be put inside the script.
Since it was made for one key, I eventually had to make it work for every each key on the page.

I did this:

```
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function () {        
      $('#main').hide;
      $("#main").fadeIn(1000);
    });          
   });
 </script>
</head>
```

This function executes every time the page reloads and since this is a one page site with only the main text changing in the middle, it is executed on every button click. 
Aspx changes the text, jQuery immediately hides it and it fades it in slowly. There is no fade out, but this method works great also and thinking about it, I like it better.

Comment: Is this answer or it worked as explained above or more detail for question? If it is question, you need to put that in question , not in answer.

Comment: @user276... , if you are intended to post this as a `reply` for my answer post, then post this to comment ( using `add a comment`). BTW, i told you to user `animate()` - custom JS function and invoke that from button click, but you did it completely incorrect way.